# Drop and replace table in Excel via OleDb

Tags: c#, .net, oledb, excel-interop

I need to replace table created by OleDbCommand in Excel file. The new table has the same name, but could has different structure. I managed this by deleting sheet via Interop.Excel but there is problem when other sheets refer to this sheet. All formulas are lost. I noticed that creating new table via OleDbCommand creates new Defined name in Names property (Names manager). I've tried to create new table with other name, copy table headers and change name location in:

`workbook.Names.Item(ShName, Type.Missing, Type.Missing).RefersTo=oldSheetRange`

Where `oldSheetRange` is column headers range. Unfortunately when I try to insert new data rows they do not insert to the table (no error occurs).

Is there any option to replace table saving reffering formulas?

Regards, Kuba

Comment: Kuba, question and problem is a bit unclear. Is it `ListObject` which you want to change/raplece/remove? Are you sure that changing reference to named range will solve the problem? If so- the line of code seems to be partially correct. But this should be something like this (pesudocode): `workbook.Names.Item("here_named_range_name", Type.Missing, Type.Missing).RefersTo="="=Arkusz1!$A$4:$D$5";`. Is it what you have when checking values of your `ShName` and `oldSheetRange` variables?

Comment: My only purpose for changing range name is to do everything that I can to force excel to treat my new (replacing) sheet as an old. I did it because I noticed that creating table via `OleDbCommand` (`CREATE TABLE...`) creates new Name in excel workbook. All I need to achieve is to replace table in Excel file, not losing all formulas in other sheets that refer to replaced sheet. I hope the issue is more clear now.

Comment: I think the idea you have (to change `Name object` range) is ok and will work. I gave you correct syntax in my comment which works in such situation. I can't help you any more as there are too little information referring to any error message, variable values, etc.